# Why my Visual Studio creates unit test projects in VB only?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1. My project is in C#. When I add a test project, it's in VB. I can't find a way to create one in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was choosing a test document under Test projects instead of test template under Visual C#.
Still the Test Project should use C# as that's my primary language in VS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the default test project language.  Tools/Options//Test Project/Default Test Project Language.  Ever time I've installed VS, regardless of my chosen primary language, it defaults to VB.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you may have gotten switched over to the VB.Net profile.  Trying adding a new project and seeing if under VB Projects there is a node named "Other Languages".  If so C# projects should be available under that.